# shape = 19, shape = 20 and shape=16 in R graphics

Tags: r, graphics

In R graphics and ggplot2 we can specify the shape of the points. I am wondering what is the main difference between shape = 19, shape = 20 and shape = 16? Is it the size?

[image: vs]

This post might consider as a duplicate of another post. However, it discusses shape = 19 and shape = 16. How about shape = 20?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for pointing this post. It discuss size 16 and 19 and the main difference is which one has stroke. But how about shape = 20?

Comment: `shape = 20` is just a smaller filled circle, with only one `colour`.

Comment: Does it have stoke as shape = 19?

Comment: The `shape = 19` symbol seems to have a fill and stroke when examined in Illustrator. It does have only one `colour` though (that is used for both fill and stroke).

Comment: Typo. I meant `shape = 20` seems to have fill and stroke ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the only difference is the shape that your plotting points will take. As described in the ggplot documentation:

Shape 16 filled circle
shape 19 solid circle
shape 20 bullet (smaller circle)

Comment: Additionally: `shape = 16`: only respects `colour` which is used to fill the circle; there is no stroke. `shape = 19`: default in `geom_point`; only respects `colour` which is used to fill the circle and border stroke. If you want to use separate stroke and fill colours you need to use `shape > 20`.